# using OpenCV Matches

Tags: c#, opencv, feature-detection

I'm confused about what OpenCV (feature2D) Matches are, i'm using OpenCVSharp and doing something like:

```
                var pt1 = detector.Detect(img1);
                var pt2 = detector.Detect(img2);

                Mat desc1 = new Mat();
                Mat desc2 = new Mat();

                extractor.Compute(img1, ref pt1, desc1);
                extractor.Compute(img2, ref pt2, desc2);

                var matcher = new BFMatcher();
                var matches = matcher.Match(desc1, desc2);

                Cv2.DrawMatches(img1, pt1, img2, pt2, matches, target);
```

This is working just fine but instead of drawing them i want to do something out of those matches myself, however all there is in matches is an array of items with the following data : QueryIdx TrainIdx Distance and ImgIdx. ImgIdx sounds irrelevant (always 0) and all i could think of was QueryIdx and TrainIdx would be indexes respectively of points in Pt1 and Pt2, however it doesn't seem to be the case as if i take my first result in matches it has the following Data :

```
{DMatch (QueryIdx:0, TrainIdx:4, ImgIdx:0, Distance:414.4816)}
```

Which would lead to index0 of Pt1 and index4 of Pt2, if i try that i get the following data respectively :

```
{(x:1490.127 y:1808.562)}
{(x:1852.559 y:1789.147)}
```

However if i compute the distance between those points we get

```
1808.562 - 1789.147 = 19.415
1852.559 - 1490.127 = 382.432
19.415²  = 376.942
482.432² = 146254.234
376.942 + 146254.234 = 146631.176
sqrt(146631.176) = 382.431
And finally 382.431 != 414.4816
```

So what am i missing?

Comment: " what am i missing" - the DMatch distance is **not** the one between the **points**, but the one between the **descriptors**.found at those points

Comment: @berak Could you clarify? I'm still a bit confused about the API. Does this mean i'm retrieving the correct point pairs already? If not could you show me how to do it?

Comment: to find out, if it was a 'good' match, you compare the DMatch distance, not the one between points. (that's the whole idea behind 'decriptor matching'. there might be arbitrary rotation/translation between your 2 images, so the point distance is not useful.)

Comment: @berak But compare it to what? I have the dmatch distance but i'm not sure what to compare it to

Comment: small == good. see, e.g. [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html#code)

Comment: @berak What i'm trying to achieve is to retrieve all the source and dest points of the matches, not to filter them by quality (i don't care if i get false positives or if they're far). So lower distance isn't better in my case, i want all of them. I just want to be sure i'm retrieving the correct point for a match (that is that the indexes are those of the source pt arrays and that i didn't missunderstand)